# jQuery fadeIn() method not working when loading html content into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein

So here's the code I'm working with

```
<script>
    var num=0;

    $('.loadMore').click(function() {
        num+=12;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/blogtest.php',
            data: {Posts: num},
            success: function(data){
                $('.dynamic').append(data).fadeIn(3000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically it appends html data that "blogtest.php" is processing from an rss feed into a div. I wanted to get this to fade in as it's appended while leaving the data that's already been loaded intact (i.e. I don't want that to fade in). As it is my code, if it worked, I assume would fade in the entire div. Since it's not working I've been throwing everything at it to see if anything will work, but to no avail. Below is what I've tried

```
//Doesn't fade in, but does load
$('.dynamic').append(data).fadeIn(3000); 

// Doesn't fade in, but does load
$(data).appendTo('.dynamic').fadeIn(3000); 

//Doesn't display, I assume it stays hidden
$(data).hide().appendTo('.dynamic').fadeIn(3000);

//I even tried converting 'data' to an object
var data_object = $(data); //Tried all the above methods, with same results
```

So any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT----
I added a `$(document).ready()` call, but that didn't really change anything. Had the same results with the above code snippets

Comment: `$(data).hide().appendTo('.dynamic').fadeIn(3000);` This should _work_, if `.dynamic` element is visible.

Comment: Is the js before the actual html? If so, since it's not in $(document).ready() no elements have the class loadMore thus no elements will get the function added to them

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a document ready call?

Comment: No, this is after all of my html and what not, right before the '</body>' tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $node = $("<div>").html(data).hide();
$('.dynamic').append($node);
$node.fadeIn(3000);
```

should work!

Comment: This worked. Mind explaining the difference from the methods I was using. Like what is the code doing that's intrinsically different from my approach?

Comment: Well, you want only the new content to fade in. So I created a separate $node for that. It needs to be hidden, or otherwise the fadein won't have any effect. In your solutions, you either tried to fadein $('.dynamic'), which was already visible, or you tried to do $(data) which might not create a DOM node, since data is arbitrary HTML and not necessarily a nice "<div>".